# HTML Canvas Interval vs RequestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

So, maybe total brainfart here. The syntax for `setInterval()` is pretty clear. Do something every x miliseconds. How is this best translated to using the `requestAnimationFrame()` ?

I have about 300 objects and each is supposed to perform an animation sequence at a certain interval (every 8, 6, 2, etc seconds)? How can I best accomplish this using `requestAnimationFrame()` which gets called ~60 times a second? There is probably an easy answer, I just, for the life of me, can't figure it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`requestAnimationFrame` is pretty low level, it just does what you already said: roughly gets called at 60fps (assuming the browser can keep up with that pace). So typically you would need to build something on top of that, much like a game engine that has a game loop.

In my game engine, I have this (paraphased/simplified here):

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(this._doFrame);

...

_doFrame: function(timestamp) {
     var delta = timestamp - (this._lastTimestamp || timestamp);

     for(var i = 0, len = this.elements.length; i < len; ++i) {
         this.elements[i].update(delta);
     }

     this._lastTimestamp = timestamp;

     // I used underscore.js's 'bindAll' to make _doFrame always
     // get called against my game engine object
     window.requestAnimationFrame(this._doFrame);
 }
```

Then each element in my game engine knows how to update themselves. In your case each element that should update every 2, 6, 8 seconds needs to keep track of how much time has passed and update accordingly:

```
update: function(delta) {
     this.elapsed += delta;

     // has 8 seconds passed?
     if(this.elapsed >= 8000) {
          this.elapsed -= 8000;  // reset the elapsed counter
          this.doMyUpdate(); // whatever it should be
     }
 }
```

The Canvas API along with `requestAnimationFrame` are rather low level, they are the building blocks for things like animation and game engines. If possible I'd try to use an existing one like cocos2d-js or whatever else is out there these days.

Comment: thanks! this is pretty much what i was after. A little more digging revealed this: https://gist.github.com/1002116 which is essentially what you have. I think my mistake was trying to make it work inside the one main loop versus a loop for each object.

Answer (score 11):

To force requestAnimationFrame to stick to a specific FPS you can use both at once!

```
var fps = 15;
function draw() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        // Drawing code goes here
    }, 1000 / fps);
}
```

A little weird, but noth the most confusing thing in the world.

You can also use requestAnimationFrame not with FPS but with elapsed time in order to draw objects that need to be updated based on the time difference since the last call:

```
var time;
function draw() {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    var now = new Date().getTime(),
        dt = now - (time || now);
 
    time = now;
 
    // Drawing code goes here... for example updating an 'x' position:
    this.x += 10 * dt; // Increase 'x' by 10 units per millisecond
}
```

These two snippets are from [this fine article](http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/), which contains additional details.

Good question by the way! I don't think I've seen this answered on SO either (and I'm here way too much)

Comment: also, thanks! the second snippet is close to what i was after. as i stated in the comment for the first answer, this seems like what i was after: https://gist.github.com/1002116

Comment: both of the answers were really great - really appreciate it!

Comment: requestAnimationFrame sends a timestamp along as an argument. In my experience creating a new Date object is much more expensive than using the provided timestamp.

Comment: yeah you should avoid the creation of new date objects (or any new objects) in loops for performance reasons, but `mozAnimationStartTime` is only available on Firefox and I wasn't aware any other browsers implemented a provided timestamp.

Comment: the timestamp is an interesting tidbit i didn't know. so, it's exclusive to mozilla's implementation as of now?